# Would your recommend Magento CE for installing on Windows 8.1 OS

Tags: development, windows, environment-emulation

I have laptop with Windows 8.1 (64 bit) running. Now I want to develop an e-commerce website for my new start-up which is very small. Whether I can install Magento CE on my laptop with Windows 8.1 (64 bit). If so, from where I can download the CE version? Otherwise will you recommend to change the OS to Linux on laptop? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I have already done this. you can do following (overall steps)

1. Download XMAPP for windows 8.1 from below link, install it on your windows as usual
   https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html
2. Download Magento CE edition 
   http://www.magentocommerce.com/download
3. Extract and copy the files to htdocs folder of your xampp instllated directory
4. Browse the folder in browser and magento installation will start, follow the steps and you are done.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I am using 64 bit OS. The XMAPP available in the link mentioned above is 32 bit. Will it compitable?

Comment: I think yes it will work, try this link http://www.downloadx64.com/xampp/

Comment: I have done Step 1, 2  & 3. But in step 4, I am unable to figure it out how to install Magento CE. Request your help please. Thanks.

Comment: did you copied magento source code to some folder ? what is name of folder ? browse it with http://localhost/myfirstmagentoweb/

Answer (score 1):

I would highly suggest either using a small VPS from a provider like [Digital Ocean](http://digitalocean.com) or using [Vagrant](http://vagrantup.com) to setup a Linux server environment that mirrors the host you plan to use.